# Can't connect to SQL Server 2008 from PHP

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have experience with mysql databases and have successfully connected to them with a couple dozen projects.

Now, I’m having trouble connecting to a SQL Server 2008. This works: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv sections appear on this page. Here’s the code that I’m using to connect:

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

This code is straight from php.net here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php. The only changes I made were replacing serverName\sqlexpress with ##.#.#.##. And changing: dbName, username, password.

Here is the results when I run the connection code above:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$serverName' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\inetpub\quote.myWebsite.com\index.php on line 23

Even if I run something simple like this:

```
<?php $myVariable = "someString"; ?>
```

I get the same type of parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$myVariable' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\inetpub\quote.myWebsite.com\index.php on line 23

Why am I receiving the errors in my PHP code?

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with sql server, it's a purely PHP syntax error.

Comment: There isn't `23` lines in this code, how are you using it? Plus, that link seems to contain a port number `$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress, 1542"; //serverName` which you don't have.

Comment: What is on line 23 of your index.php file?

Comment: I've discovered my mistake. The first line, (which I removed because it had my user name and pw) looked like this:

<?php//some comment

It should have had a space after php, like this: 

<?php //some comment

Answer (score 1):

You have a string escaping error. Open this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and search for the string "Escaped characters" (without quotes). Escape sequence **\s** does not exist though.

Change this line from this: `$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";` to this: `$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress";`. Looking closely I just doubled the backslash (**\\**).